# Go Http Post request with basic auth and formvalue

Tags: http, go, wrapper

I am writing a wrapper for an API in go. The api uses basic auth and then POST request requires PostForm value. I'm doing something like this:

```
func NewFoo(name string) string {
    client := &http.Client{}
    URL := HOST + "foo/"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", URL, nil)
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("name", name)
    req.Form = v
    req.SetBasicAuth(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    s := string(bodyText)
    return s
}
```

I had a similar, GET request without the form value and it works. When I run it, it tells me that the "name" value is required. (so it's not getting it)

Is there any reason this does not work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

```
// Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL
// field's query parameters and the POST or PUT form data.
// This field is only available after ParseForm is called.
// The HTTP client ignores Form and uses Body instead.
Form url.Values
```

You have to pass your `url.Values` to the request's body instead.

```
func NewFoo(name string) string {
    client := &http.Client{}
    URL := HOST + "foo/"
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("name", name)
    //pass the values to the request's body
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", URL, strings.NewReader(v.Encode()))
    req.SetBasicAuth(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    s := string(bodyText)
    return s
}
```

Comment: Good catch @collinglass, for some reason I thought `url.Values` had a `.String()` func.

Comment: adding `req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` will help if you post Form :)

Comment: @vigo I knew that something was missing somewhere :-) (note: `http.PostForm` adds that header by default, but `NewRequest()...Do()` does not). Also, consider using `http.MethodPost` instead of the literal `"POST"`.